# How cancel files from queue programmatically in JQuery File Upload Plugin?

Tags: jquery-plugins, file-upload, queue

When user add a file into queue I must validate so I wrote a function in callback:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        check = ValidaDoc(file.name);
        if (check!="OK"){
            var erro="";
            if (check=="Alerta1"){
                alert("Alerta1");
            }
            else {
                errotemp="";
                if(check=="Erro1"){erro=erro + file.name + " com extensão não esperada.";}
                else if(check=="Erro2"){erro=erro + file.name + " não cadastrado ou com nome fora do padrão.";}
                $($('#fileupload .files .cancel button')[index]).click();
        }
    }
});
});
```

The callback works, the ValidaDoc function works and a file is canceled but not the right one. I think the index use is no right. Anyone have a ideia?

Comment: Think I got it. This index is for $,each function not the files order in table. So I rewrite the click to:"$($('#fileupload .files .cancel button')[data.context[index].rowIndex]).click();"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was my misunderstaning of the index. I replace the line that calls click with the one bellow and all works fine.

```
$($('#fileupload .files .cancel button')[data.context[index].rowIndex]).click();
```

I have to change the event too. When the fileuploadadd is called the file is not in the table yet. So changed to fileuploadded.

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadadded', function (e, data) {
```

Comment: I've been looking for this for hours - you rock!!